# How to use openLdap?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm sorry, but I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask. But is there anyone out there that can teach me a step by step guide on how to use OpenLdap? There isn't any GUI and I'm unfamiliar with it. I'm trying to create a user in there.
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an LDAP browser. There are many free ones available, e.g. Userbooster Light, JXplorer, ...